# Calculate as much as the value increases with a fixed value

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the total amount for each person with the following for statement.

The default is 3 people and the cost is 50 dollars,
By default, we want to add $10 for each additional person.

For example,
When the number of people stored is 6, 6 people * 50 dollars = not 300 dollars
3 people (default $50) + 3 people (additional $30) = $80.

I'm trying to get it as above.

```
for ($i=0; $row=sql_fetch_array($result); $i++) {
  $standard = '50';

  if ($row['person'] > 3) {
    echo $person_calculate = $row['person'] * $standard;
  }
  else
  {
    echo '0';
  }

}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What are sample values of `$row['person']`?  You’re looping through database results (albeit in a rather unorthodox way), but you’re comparing the value of person instead of the actual count of people.

Comment: @TimMorton The value of $row['person'] stores the total number of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to use basic algebra...

Given the following values:

```
$breakPoint = 3;
$basis = 50;
$secondary = 10;
$population = $row['person'];

$total = $breakPoint * $basis + ($population - $breakPoint) * $secondary;
```

Now, just stick it in a loop:

```
<?php
// get db connection info
// ...

$stmt = $pdo->query('your query here');

$breakPoint = 3;
$basis = 50;
$secondary = 10;

// loop through db results
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    // set default value if 3 or fewer
    $total = $breakPoint * $basis;

    /: calculate for over 3 
    if($row['person'] > 3) {
        $total = $breakPoint * $basis + ($population - $breakPoint) * $secondary;
    }
    print $total . '<br>';
}
```

#### Important note

You are working with a deprecated version of php! You need to upgrade to take advantage of PDO or mysqli.

See this site for info on [how to use PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)